# Adding a Component Results in Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) > or a class/function

Tags: reactjs

I have a `SocialItems` component which I'm using in 3 places on my site. It has successfully been added to the site header and hero elements, but when adding it to the Footer I get an error. The Footer component works fine without it.

Error Message:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render
> method of `Footer`.

footer.js:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { UtilityContainer } from "../utils/utility";

import SocialItems from "../utils/social_items";

const Footer = ({ data }) => (
  <FooterStop>
    <h4>the footer</h4>
    <ul>
      {data.footer.frontmatter.columns.map((column) => (
        <div key={column.id}>
          {column.column_title}
          <ul>
            {column.links.map((link) => (
              <li key={link.link.id}>
                <a href={link.link.url}>{link.link.content}</a>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      ))}
    </ul>
    <SocialItems />
  </FooterStop>
);

export default Footer;

const FooterStop = styled(UtilityContainer)`
  scroll-snap-align: end;
  background-color: var(--col-header);
`;
```

social_items.js:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import Facebook from "../../svg/facebook.svg";
import Twitter from "../../svg/twitter.svg";
import Phone from "../../svg/phone.svg";
import Mail from "../../svg/mail.svg";

import { UtilityNavList } from "./utility";

export const SocialItems = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <UtilityNavList>
        <li>
          <StyledLink href="facebook.com" circle>
            <Facebook />
          </StyledLink>
        </li>

        <li>
          <StyledLink href="twitter.com">
            <Twitter />
          </StyledLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <StyledLink href="phone.com">
            <Phone />
          </StyledLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <StyledLink href="contact.com">
            <Mail />
          </StyledLink>
        </li>
      </UtilityNavList>
    </>
  );
};

const StyledLink = styled.a`
  --fg: var(--col-fg, var(--col-light));
  --ac: var(--col-ac, var(--col-header));

  display: flex;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 1000vh;
  color: var(--col-light);
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease-in-out, color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    background-color: var(--fg);
    border-color: var(--ac);
    color: var(--ac);
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty much clear, you're doing a named export in `social_items.js` while try to import it as a default export, change your import to:

```
import { SocialItems } from "../utils/social_items";
```

Comment: Thanks. Some days you just stare at something for too long!

Comment: don't worry, it happens to all of us. sometimes you only need another developer to look at your code